# Catch dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-traversing

I am using javascript to generate a div witch i want to use Perfect Scrollbar and i cannot catch it with its id to initiate the plug in. I know how to do it if i want to bind an event but i am confused about this.
Here i generate the div

```
var search = $('<div id="search-container"><h2>SEARCH VOICES BY NAME</h2>    <input type="text" size="30" id="voice-inp"><div id="search"></div></div>');
```

And the initiate code:

```
var search = $('#search');
Ps.initialize(search);
```

EDIT. I catch the element now but i get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Comment: The id is `search-container` so you need `#search-container` to access it

Comment: There is also a search id.

Comment: Ah I missed that one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Ps takes an container object, you likely want

```
var $search = $('<div id="search-container"><h2>SEARCH VOICES BY NAME</h2>    <input type="text" size="30" id="voice-inp"><div id="search"></div></div>');


Ps.initialize($search);
```

OR

```
$('<div id="search-container"><h2>SEARCH VOICES BY NAME</h2>    <input type="text" size="30" id="voice-inp"><div id="search"></div></div>')
.appendTo("body");


Ps.initialize($("#search-container"));
```